# Using storyboard, sub view loses data when closed. Trying to understand why and resolve

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created an app with two different calculator views, each one with a separate view controller and separate nib file. I set up a tab bar on the each view to switch back and forth between views. When I switch views each view controller retains whatever data has been input.

I recreated the same app using the storyboard feature. So now I have one nib file only with the same two view controllers.  But when I transition between views I lose whatever data has been input on the second view.  I am wondering why I now lose the data and how to retain it when leaving the sub view.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because the storyboard is being more aggressive about releasing view controllers that are no longer on screen. I expect you would have seen the same behavior with separate nibs in high memory pressure situations.

In short, you as the programmer should design your view controllers *expecting* them to be released as soon as possible. Work out a plan for simple data persistence to ensure that the user's data is always available. Don't count on view controller objects sticking around to ensure that the state is preserved.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I will work on saving the data when the view closes.